# Bootstap make own container without Saas

Tags: html, css

Using bootstrap 5, I need a custom container, can't figure out how to constrain the class = "container-fluid" to the desired size?

[1144px - bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxHpY.png)

[1370px - good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZD3S.png)

HTML here:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-3">
<div class="row row-cols-auto px-1">
<div class="card-group">
<div class="col">
<div class="card mb-3 btn_3new" style="max-width: 22rem;">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="row px-4 py-2 "><p class="card12-header"></p></div>
<div class="row px-2">
<p class="card-text">1</p>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Create your own css class of desired size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using container-fluid, which tells your code that you want to take up as much space as possible.

Bootstrap comes with three different containers:

.container, which sets a max-width at each responsive breakpoint

.container-fluid, which is width: 100% at all breakpoints

.container-{breakpoint}, which is width: 100% until the specified breakpoint
so if you're trying to constrain your container to a certain size, you may not want to use .container-fluid.

For example,
If I extrapolate your code with .container, I get this: https://codepen.io/dainaa-the-lessful/pen/jOBpNJN

```
<div class="container px-3">
  <div class="row row-cols-auto px-1">
    <div class="card-group">
      <div class="col ms-2 me-2">
        <div class="card mb-3 btn_3new" style="max-width: 22rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row px-4 py-2 ">
              <p class="card12-header"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row px-2">
              <p class="card-text">1</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Which you can then set a margin property on the cards for.